# Microsoft Graph API - How to query granted permissions to my app id?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing an web application that is works 100% on a top of Microsoft Graph.

I only want to request the definetly required permissions to the current logged in user, as such I'm looking for a way to query what permissions my app currently has on login.

Do you know how to query what permissions the Tenant Admin and current user granted to my app?

I've found that "Application Get" seems to be able to do that, but requires Directory permissions that I wanted to avoid.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Thanks,
Ralm

Comment: The `AuthenticationResult` object you get back from the MSAL library includes a `Scopes` property that will show what permissions your app has. So if you cannot find a Graph API to query it, maybe that'll be a good workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the info .
I'm using the JS version and just checked. 
It seems the only way I can get the "AuthenticationResult" is on the login response, which is a problem due to page reloads, etc.
Addicionally, it seems that the "Scopes" property is not being populated in the Javascript version, I got an empty array, although I have many permissions granted both by Admin Consent and User Consent.

Comment: @Brad 
Are you using the Javascript version of the library also?
I'm wondering what am I missing :( 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah sorry, I only have experience with the .NET SDK. But the response the server sends from login should include the data, so I imagine that it's available in the Javascript SDK somehow as well.

Comment: @brad yeah, ok.
I've submitted a bug in Github, hopefully gets fixed soon as the library creates an abstraction to the server response.

Comment: So, this is not possible with JS library it seems:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/853